# ERROR: `require': cannot load such file -- bindata (LoadError) ( using pcap_tools gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pcap

Maybe im dumb, but i get this error

```
/home/deniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bindata (LoadError)
```

I already install the gem and added in gemfile and did bundle update but when i tried to rails s my project appears that error...

Help! and thanks!

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org`'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
gem 'execjs'
gem 'pcap_tools'
```

Bundle install

```
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using Platform (0.4.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.2) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.2) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.2) 
Using activemodel (4.0.2) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.2) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using open4 (1.3.0) 
Using ox (2.0.11) 
Using popen4 (0.1.2) 
Using pcap_tools (0.0.6) 
Using pg (0.17.1) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.2) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.1) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1) 
Using rails (4.0.2) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and output of `bundle install`?

Comment: Ready. Bundle install run perfect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. I talked to the person who created the gem and he push the new version.

https://github.com/bpaquet/pcap_tools

https://github.com/bpaquet/pcap_tools/issues/8